# Android Internal and External Storage

Tags: android, storage, android-sdcard

I have an app that accesses music and I had at least one user complain that some of his songs are on internal storage and that causes a force close.

My question is do I have to do 2 calls for each song now or can I make a query that will look at both the internal and external memory?

Answer (score 0):

Multimedia is not my strong suit, but I would think the media scanner would keep an index of what is where. Another option would be to look at startup where the media files are located and record this data in `SharedPreferences` for later use.

Answer (score 0):

look at my answer in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13935210/1716620

ContentProvider is the key

i have an application that use external and internal memory to save pictures and i needed to use gallery to view them in some rircumstance and it gave error if i tried to pass an uri that pointed to an internal memory

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13935210/1716620

that way i solved my problem... and your :)

Answer (score -1):

It depends on how the manufacturer implemented their MediaProvider/Scanner etc. as there is no standard for more than one flash(SD) device.